# How to make Google Script wait 3 seconds between two functions? The 2 functions are in 1 button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, tracking

**ABOUT:** I made a [Google Script Web App](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxVVpWgxBU2wpXrcR2ebPfkGLqIAOO82_pgEv__8rTsjlJ31h8Uk-JKDgl0P8tn1HgW-Q/exec) for tracking packages for our freight company. The database is on [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12sC7HsR9q4k1hjZOrWIjVQuq8xtQatzvEueJeI2rhnA/edit?usp=sharing), with two sheets named "Tracker" and "Program" to automatically track packages.

**PROCESS:**

1. On the web app I enter the *Tracking Number*
2. On click, this gets sent to the *Tracker sheet*
3. *Program sheet* gets the tracking number from *Tracker sheet*, and takes 2-3 seconds to get data
4. The data from *Program sheet* (which only has 1 row of data - only the relevant data) gets sent back to the web app for the client to view

**MY PROBLEM:** I need to have Steps 2 & 4 execute with 1 click of a button. Right now, it can do so if I fill up the form twice (which is a hassle for the clients).

**QUESTION:** Is there a way I can execute Step 2 first, then Google Script waits 3 seconds before executing Step 4? In just 1 click of the button

```
// STEP 2 where tracking number gets sent to Sheets
function sendTracking(formObject) {
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
  document.getElementById("myForm");
}

// STEP 4 where tracking status is returned from Sheets to Web App
function trackingInfo(formObject) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createTable).processReturnForm(formObject);
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

---

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**
All these returned blank -- I've placed all of them in between the two functions of Step 2 & 4. I'm not sure if I'm just entering them wrong or if they really don't work with my functions.

- SpreadsheetApp.flush();
- Utilities.sleep(3000)
- LockService.getScriptLock(); lock.waitLock();

```
// COMBINED: Process STEP 2 & 4
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  sendTracking(formObject); // THIS IS STEP 2
  // codes above inserted here
  trackingInfo(formObject); // THIS IS STEP 4
}
```

---

**OTHER RELEVANT CODES:**

**The code behind Step 2:**

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "URL";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Tracker");

ws.getRange('D3').setValue(formObject.trackingNumber);
}
```

**The code behind Step 4:**

```
function processReturnForm(formObject){  
  var result = "";
  if(formObject.trackingNumber){//Execute if form passes search text
  result = search(formObject.trackingNumber);
  }
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place it at the end of `processForm` or at the beginning of your `SuccessHandler`.

As I answered in your previous question. The execution sequence is not ensured in your code. Please first fix that.

```js
Utilities.sleep(3000);
```

Reference:

[sleep(milliseconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)

Comment: I’ll try this one later thank you! Oh yeah, I noted your prev answer too! Sorry I deleted my previous question, I think this new one best describes my problem

Comment: Hey! Just wanted to say thank you! I used your previous answer, then I added an if-else condition and getrangevalues, and it finally worked! Thank you so much!